# No Such User Here error when sending via form

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I have an online form that is being sent to my client's email. Unfortunately I am getting a "No Such User Here" error when submitted. If I test out the form on my email or my coworker's email, it works fine.

The email exists because they have told me they use it to send and receive other email.

Error looks like this:

> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>      recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
>
> ```
>  <client's email>
>    No Such User Here
> ```

Edit: For what it's worth, here's my code. I'm using Processwire and using the Form Template Processor module. Which I've used before. This form works perfectly when sent to any email but my client's. I'm thinking this is more of an MX records thing which I'm not super well-versed in.

```
<?php
 $form = $modules->get('FormTemplateProcessor'); 
 $form->template = $templates->get('form'); // required
 $form->requiredFields = array('first_name','last_name','company','email','phone');
 $form->email = 'CLIENTS EMAIL'; // optional, sends form as email
 $form->parent = $page; // optional, saves form as page
 echo '<div class="form-header"><h2>Become a member today</h2></div>';
 echo $form->render(); // draw form or process submitted form
?>
```

Comment: triple check the email address. i trust the error message over what you claim

Comment: @nogad I did. Several times.

Comment: so test that email address. send something to it DIRECTLY from your own personal mail client. don't involve php at all.  if that bounces, then the user is lying to you about it being valid, or they're deluded about what their address really is.

Comment: @Marc B What if it doesn't bounce?

Comment: consider email the same as the postal service. there's you (sender), the postal service (smtp servers, local mtas), and the recipient (the user). if you've eliminated the user as a problem, then you start checking the postal service to see where that's screwing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons why you would get a "550 No Such User Here" error.

> 1. Mail file permissions are not readable or are incorrect.
> 2. The email address was typed incorrectly.
> 3. MX records are incorrect ( pointing to the wrong server ).
> 4. Email does not route correctly ( Remote / Local domains ).

To dig further kindly go through this article [Source](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/bounceback-errors/fixing-no-such-user-here)

*Credits to the [Source](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/bounceback-errors/fixing-no-such-user-here) Poster @James Richardson*

Comment: Number 4 worked for me. Email routing was set to local, changed to remote. Error gone. Thank you!

Comment: @AlyQ Awesome to hear that it helped you mate :-)